# Sending URL from input field onClick file:///

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a HTML page with a form with a URL input field. When you type the URL into the input field and click the button, I want it to redirect me to that URL. Instead, it's putting the URL at the end of file:///Users/Desktop/index.html/www.google.co.uk. My webpage is only local atm, is it possible to do this?

```
$("#submit").click(function sendurl()
  let url = document.getElementById('web-address').value
  window.location.href = url;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to prepend "http://" to the final URL:

```js
$("#submit").click(function sendurl(event) {
    // In case of <input type="submit">
    event.preventDefault();
    
    let url = document.getElementById('web-address').value;
    if(url && !url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
        url = "http://" + url;
    }
    
    window.location = url;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
     <input type="text" id="web-address">
     <input type="button" id="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need is replacing browser url with address name and correct origin name like this example

```
window.location.replace(url)
```

Comment: Surely you mean `//` not `\\\`

Comment: I tested ,it works if you add "http:\\" to your url and replace it instead of current address it will work perfectly .It is exactly like "url = "http://" + url;" but with another way

Comment: That's only because the browser is being nice to you, it is noticing and correcting your mistake. Notice that the final address which ends up in the address bar has `//` in it - the browser translated an invalid URL into a valid one that it can use. If you try with backslashes in some other non-browser HTTP client (e.g. PostMan as just one example), then it will simply fail. P.S. You can also read in the [URL specification](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt) that forward slashes must be used (see the section "Internet protocol parts")

Comment: What I wanted tried to refer was  replace function and about the others I agree that you are right and I am corrected my previous answer

Answer (score -2):

just change this : `window.location.href = url;`

to this

```
 window.location = url;
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that but still doing the same. Is it anything to do with the form action/method??

    <form class="geturl" action="index.html" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

Comment: Can you explain **why** that should help?